# How to check all changes in project under git?

Tags: git, phpstorm

How can I check all changes in project under git I made since last pull ?
git status
shows only modified files, I want to see code too.
I use PhpStorm 2020.3.1 in my work, but all git commands I do in the console.

I would prefer to check all changes in PhpStorm, is that is possible or some other tools.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last pull moved your `origin/master` branch (let's talk about your `master`). To see commits since the last pull run

```
git log origin/master..master
```

To see code change since the last pull:

```
git diff origin/master..master
```

To split the changes per commit:

```
git log -p origin/master..master
```

(Option `-p` means "show patches in addition to commit info").

To make the commands more universal:

```
git log -p '@{u}..'
git diff '@{u}'
```

(`${u}` means "the upstream branch for the current branch"; i.e. for the current branch `master` upstream would be `origin/master`).

Comment: Thanks! looks lik git log  is what I need. has this command some pattern name filter options? Like show only files by some mask ?

Comment: Of course: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_examples

Answer (score 1):

I use the tool fork (https://git-fork.com/) as a way to see changes that I did.

The basic overview of a repository also only shows file names but if you click on “changes” you can browse through the affected files and see the actual changes in the code.

It has a free evaluation version where you are limited in the amount of repositories you can have open at once and a paid license version.

Edit: better formatting

Comment: @mstdmstd It doesn't. OSX and w32.

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff #COMPARES YOUR STAGING AREA WITH WORKING TREE
```

will show your changes in code too

to see commit hash

```
git log
```

to compare changes with a particular commit

```
git diff hash
```